# Why doesn't pip work?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed pip and everything based off of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaqhR9Ap9-E) video, and the install seemed to look great. But when I say "import pip" in IDLE, I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  import pip
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from pip.log import logger
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\log.py", line 8, in <module>
  from pip import backwardcompat
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pip\backwardcompat\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
 console_encoding = sys.__stdout__.encoding
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You generally don't use pip by importing it; it's used as a command line tool. And running anything from IDLE is generally a bad idea anyway; it's awful and often makes programs act weird. Sadly, there aren't really any core python developers who can be bothered to make it better because none of them use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't import pip from within IDLE, you are supposed to call it from the command line. It is expecting there to be a stdout, but it looks like there is not one from within IDLE.

Comment: So then how would I use to install a module?

Comment: Open up a terminal, and type `pip install <module>`

Comment: "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

Comment: Find where `pip` was installed, generally something like `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`, then add that directory to your `PATH` environment variable. I don't have a Windows machine in front of me to check, but it's somewhere in your System Settings under "Advanced" or the like. Once you're there, find the environment variable for `PATH`, and add the directory that `pip.exe` is located in to that list.

Comment: As said, it is meant to be run from the command line.  However, it needs to be in your path, which means two directories need to be in your PATH (in my case C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts).  pip.exe is installed into Scripts.

Comment: beat me by 32 seconds!

Comment: Nevermind, guys... Thanks for your help but easy_install worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python -
```

Try Above command that will fetch latest code for PIP from the PyPy.